# Xcode 6: Images Not Showing Up On Device

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am creating UIImageView(s) and adding these views to a UIScrollView. The images show up when I am testing on a simulator, but when I test on an iphone 5s the images don't show up. Below is a list of things I have tried:

1. Clean Build
2. Reinstall App
3. Then I thought maybe it was a problem with retina images so I added retina images (the images are white pngs): 
   [image]

   - I am using the images as such:

     UIButton *doneBttn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [doneBttn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [doneBttn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButtonSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
     [doneBttn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50 , 30)];
     [doneBttn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [uiNavView addMenuBarButtonRight:doneBttn];
   - I know the code above works, because the image is displayed in the simulator.

What do I need to change to get the image to display on my device? Also, I have checked to make sure the files are in the xcode project directory, and not just linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this issue once, the cause of this issue was that I am not taking care of image name by assigning it to `UIImageView`, make sure that you are assigning `UIImageView` the exact name of the image as it is in the main bundle.

The simulator can read the image name if there is any case-sensitive issue or some extension issue like i.e. .png , .jpg, but device never reads the image name if there are issues in the naming conventions, device always treat the image name as exact.

Comment: I was testing on Xcode 6 while my device was still on IOS7. I am not sure what the problem was but after renaming things and updating my phone the graphics are showing up again. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPelletier when you say 'updating my phone' did you mean updating to iOS8 Beta? Or Updating to 7.1.1?